# aws high latency in same VPC Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

We are facing the connectivity latency issues between the instances. I have calculated the connection time between the two instances in the same VPC using the command time trace-route.
Sometime the connections is fast but sometime it takes around 5 sec to complete time trace-route.
Here is the log of latency.

time traceroute 10.0.0.63
traceroute to 10.0.0.63 (10.0.0.63), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.63 (10.0.0.63)  0.236 ms  0.226 ms *

real    0m5.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

Please let us know if you need any more information.

Note: We are concerning about the amazon instance.

Comment: Just run a simple ping from one to the other and post the results.

Comment: ping 10.0.0.63
PING 10.0.0.63 (10.0.0.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.345 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.379 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.352 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.409 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.421 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.381 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.63: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.394 ms

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because only amazon support could possibly address this.